# Fundamental domain of a cyclic group on $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: group-theory, euclidean-geometry, group-actions, cyclic-groups

The Wikipedia says it is a circular sector with an angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, but wouldn't it be a lune with the same angle? Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the action of $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ on $\mathbb R^3$ ?

Comment: @N.H. Rotation by 2pi/n around an axis orthogonal to the vector?

Comment: Which vector ? If the vector is fixed (say $v = (0,0,1)$ and act by rotation, then the fundamental domain is exactly a circular sector $A = \{ (x,y,z) : \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) \in [0, \frac{2\pi}{n}) \}$.

Comment: @N.H. But isn't a fundamental domain defined as a collection of points from orbits for all x $\in \mathbb{R^3}$, not just from a fixed plane?

Comment: N.H.'s comment gave a three-dimensional region, which is not in a plane.

Comment: There are no conditions on $z$, so this is 3-dimensional. Keep in mind that e.g a full cylinder which is 3-dimensional can also be described by $\{(x,y,z) : x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$.

Comment: Yes, I see. This is quite ambiguous though. Thanks for answering!